# Cyrillic problems on Mac

Tags: fonts, cyrillic, mac

I've downloaded MacTex along with TexStudio, and now I've spent several days trying to make it compile Russian texts. It seems, I've tried every single type of sudo command mentioned on this site without considerable results. Now I work with this preamble, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}

\begin{document}
Помогите мне {\it прошу вас} {\bfseries пожалуйста}

\end{document}
```

This ends up with

```
Font T2A/cmr/m/it/10=lati1000 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found...
Font T2A/cmr/bx/n/10=labx1000 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found...
```

So I assume all of the problems occur as I try to make something either bold or italic or switch the documentclass to book. And I'm sort of afraid of even thinking about integrating hyper references or specific chapter numerations. As I am new to Mac all along, please-please treat me as the dumbest person, specifying each and every step. But any help will do.

Thanks in any case

Comment: Do you have `cm-super` installed?

Comment: If you have installed the full MacTeX there should be no problem, because the missing TFM files are generated on the fly. Can you start a Terminal window and type `which pdftex` followed by return? What's the shown output?

Comment: @Bernard Tex Live tells me that I have

Comment: @egreg The output is "/usr/texbin/pdftex". It appears to me that the main problem is TexStudio itself, as TexShop managed to make a pdf out of it. If so, could you perhaps advise some other editor? Btw, TexShop totally ignores some changes, as, for instance, \titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\fontsize{12}{17}\itshape \bfseries}{ \thesubsubsection }{1em}{}... Still don't know how to deal with them

Comment: My guess is that TeXStudio has wrong paths for the programs. Check in the preferences if `pdflatex` is preceded by `/usr/texbin` or something else

Answer (score 0):

Install the cmsuper fonts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}

\begin{document}
Помогите мне {\it прошу вас} {\bfseries пожалуйста}

\sffamily
Помогите мне {\it прошу вас} {\bfseries пожалуйста}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How should this solve the problem? The first line still uses `lati1000` and `labx1000`.

Comment: no, it uses SFxx1000 ...

Comment: In output, yes. But the OP's problem is that the TFM files are not generated, so the output won't be generated in the first place.

Comment: the `t2alm*` are missing or at least in the wrong place. However, Latin Modern ha no cyrillic characters. `cmsuper` has the `t2a` encoding files.

Comment: You're confusing the levels. The font definition files don't belong to `cmsuper`, which just has Type1 fonts and, indeed, `t2acmr.fd` that's loaded by that example file, belongs in `.../tex/latex/cyrillic`. The file `t2almr.fd` has nothing to do with Latin Modern, but is not loaded anyway. Note that if `t2acmr.fd` was misplaced or missing, LaTeX would have no clue about the need of `lati1000.tfm` or `labx1000.tfm`.